# (EE) [mi] EQ overflowing -> freeze

Tags: debian, freeze, radeon

My system just froze. I waited a few minutes but nothing happened. I could not "Ctrl+1", I had to REISUB.

I'm running a Debian Jessie with a Radeon R7 240 GPU, using the free radeon driver.

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Oland PRO [Radeon R7 240]
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series]
```

and a recent kernel:

```
4.6.0-0.bpo.1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.6.4-1~bpo8+1 (2016-08-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here's what Xorg log says:

```
(EE) [mi] EQ overflowing.  Additional events will be discarded until existing events are processed.
(EE)
(EE) Backtrace:
(EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x56) [0x55fb068dad46]
(EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (mieqEnqueue+0x24b) [0x55fb068bbc9b]
(EE) 2: /usr/bin/X (QueuePointerEvents+0x52) [0x55fb06792e12]
(EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f7a54f5d000+0x609a) [0x7f7a54f6309a]
(EE) 4: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f7a54f5d000+0x655d) [0x7f7a54f6355d]
(EE) 5: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x95918) [0x55fb067b9918]
(EE) 6: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0xbfbe9) [0x55fb067e3be9]
(EE) 7: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7f7a59290000+0x350e0) [0x7f7a592c50e0]
(EE) 8: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x7f7a5a39d000+0x198d8) [0x7f7a5a3b68d8]
(EE) 9: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x7f7a5a39d000+0x57d31) [0x7f7a5a3f4d31]
(EE) 10: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (pixman_image_composite32+0x451) [0x7f7a5a3a8711]
(EE) 11: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so (fbComposite+0x208) [0x7f7a4e4ec5b8]
(EE) 12: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so (0x7f7a54906000+0x1ac30) [0x7f7a54920c30]
(EE) 13: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so (0x7f7a54906000+0x1b4db) [0x7f7a549214db]
(EE) 14: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x13d3b1) [0x55fb068613b1]
(EE) 15: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x133064) [0x55fb06857064]
(EE) 16: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x573f7) [0x55fb0677b3f7]
(EE) 17: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x5b596) [0x55fb0677f596]
(EE) 18: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f7a592b1b45]
(EE) 19: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x4590e) [0x55fb0676990e]
(EE)
(EE) [mi] These backtraces from mieqEnqueue may point to a culprit higher up the stack.
(EE) [mi] mieq is *NOT* the cause.  It is a victim.
(EE) [mi] EQ overflow continuing.  100 events have been dropped.
(EE)
(EE) Backtrace:
(EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x56) [0x55fb068dad46]
(EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (QueuePointerEvents+0x52) [0x55fb06792e12]
(EE) 2: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f7a54f5d000+0x609a) [0x7f7a54f6309a]
(EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f7a54f5d000+0x655d) [0x7f7a54f6355d]
(EE) 4: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x95918) [0x55fb067b9918]
(EE) 5: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0xbfbe9) [0x55fb067e3be9]
(EE) 6: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7f7a59290000+0x350e0) [0x7f7a592c50e0]
(EE) 7: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x7f7a5a39d000+0x198d8) [0x7f7a5a3b68d8]
(EE) 8: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x7f7a5a39d000+0x57d31) [0x7f7a5a3f4d31]
(EE) 9: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (pixman_image_composite32+0x451) [0x7f7a5a3a8711]
(EE) 10: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so (fbComposite+0x208) [0x7f7a4e4ec5b8]
(EE) 11: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so (0x7f7a54906000+0x1ac30) [0x7f7a54920c30]
(EE) 12: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so (0x7f7a54906000+0x1b4db) [0x7f7a549214db]
(EE) 13: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x13d3b1) [0x55fb068613b1]
(EE) 14: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x133064) [0x55fb06857064]
(EE) 15: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x573f7) [0x55fb0677b3f7]
(EE) 16: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x5b596) [0x55fb0677f596]
(EE) 17: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f7a592b1b45]
(EE) 18: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x4590e) [0x55fb0676990e]
(EE)
(EE) [mi] EQ overflow continuing.  200 events have been dropped.
(EE)
(EE) Backtrace:
(EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x56) [0x55fb068dad46]
(EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (QueuePointerEvents+0x52) [0x55fb06792e12]
(EE) 2: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f7a54f5d000+0x609a) [0x7f7a54f6309a]
(EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f7a54f5d000+0x655d) [0x7f7a54f6355d]
(EE) 4: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x95918) [0x55fb067b9918]
(EE) 5: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0xbfbe9) [0x55fb067e3be9]
(EE) 6: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7f7a59290000+0x350e0) [0x7f7a592c50e0]
(EE) 7: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x7f7a5a39d000+0x198d8) [0x7f7a5a3b68d8]
(EE) 8: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x7f7a5a39d000+0x57d31) [0x7f7a5a3f4d31]
(EE) 9: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (pixman_image_composite32+0x451) [0x7f7a5a3a8711]
(EE) 10: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so (fbComposite+0x208) [0x7f7a4e4ec5b8]
(EE) 11: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so (0x7f7a54906000+0x1ac30) [0x7f7a54920c30]
(EE) 12: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so (0x7f7a54906000+0x1b4db) [0x7f7a549214db]
(EE) 13: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x13d3b1) [0x55fb068613b1]
(EE) 14: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x133064) [0x55fb06857064]
(EE) 15: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x573f7) [0x55fb0677b3f7]
(EE) 16: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x5b596) [0x55fb0677f596]
(EE) 17: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f7a592b1b45]
(EE) 18: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x4590e) [0x55fb0676990e]
(EE)
(EE) [mi] EQ overflow continuing.  300 events have been dropped.
(EE)
(EE) Backtrace:
(EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x56) [0x55fb068dad46]
(EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (QueuePointerEvents+0x52) [0x55fb06792e12]
(EE) 2: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f7a54f5d000+0x609a) [0x7f7a54f6309a]
(EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f7a54f5d000+0x655d) [0x7f7a54f6355d]
(EE) 4: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x95918) [0x55fb067b9918]
(EE) 5: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0xbfbe9) [0x55fb067e3be9]
(EE) 6: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7f7a59290000+0x350e0) [0x7f7a592c50e0]
(EE) 7: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x7f7a5a39d000+0x198d8) [0x7f7a5a3b68d8]
(EE) 8: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x7f7a5a39d000+0x57d31) [0x7f7a5a3f4d31]
(EE) 9: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (pixman_image_composite32+0x451) [0x7f7a5a3a8711]
(EE) 10: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so (fbComposite+0x208) [0x7f7a4e4ec5b8]
(EE) 11: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so (0x7f7a54906000+0x1ac30) [0x7f7a54920c30]
(EE) 12: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so (0x7f7a54906000+0x1b4db) [0x7f7a549214db]
(EE) 13: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x13d3b1) [0x55fb068613b1]
(EE) 14: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x133064) [0x55fb06857064]
(EE) 15: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x573f7) [0x55fb0677b3f7]
(EE) 16: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x5b596) [0x55fb0677f596]
(EE) 17: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f7a592b1b45]
(EE) 18: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x4590e) [0x55fb0676990e]
(EE)
(EE) [mi] EQ overflow continuing.  400 events have been dropped.
(EE)
(EE) Backtrace:
(EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x56) [0x55fb068dad46]
(EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (QueuePointerEvents+0x52) [0x55fb06792e12]
(EE) 2: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f7a54f5d000+0x609a) [0x7f7a54f6309a]
(EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f7a54f5d000+0x655d) [0x7f7a54f6355d]
(EE) 4: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x95918) [0x55fb067b9918]
(EE) 5: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0xbfbe9) [0x55fb067e3be9]
(EE) 6: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7f7a59290000+0x350e0) [0x7f7a592c50e0]
(EE) 7: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x7f7a5a39d000+0x198d8) [0x7f7a5a3b68d8]
(EE) 8: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x7f7a5a39d000+0x57d31) [0x7f7a5a3f4d31]
(EE) 9: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (pixman_image_composite32+0x451) [0x7f7a5a3a8711]
(EE) 10: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so (fbComposite+0x208) [0x7f7a4e4ec5b8]
(EE) 11: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so (0x7f7a54906000+0x1ac30) [0x7f7a54920c30]
(EE) 12: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so (0x7f7a54906000+0x1b4db) [0x7f7a549214db]
(EE) 13: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x13d3b1) [0x55fb068613b1]
(EE) 14: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x133064) [0x55fb06857064]
(EE) 15: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x573f7) [0x55fb0677b3f7]
(EE) 16: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x5b596) [0x55fb0677f596]
(EE) 17: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f7a592b1b45]
(EE) 18: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x4590e) [0x55fb0676990e]
(EE)
(EE) [mi] EQ overflow continuing.  500 events have been dropped.
(EE)
(EE) Backtrace:
(EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x56) [0x55fb068dad46]
(EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (QueuePointerEvents+0x52) [0x55fb06792e12]
(EE) 2: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f7a54f5d000+0x609a) [0x7f7a54f6309a]
(EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f7a54f5d000+0x655d) [0x7f7a54f6355d]
(EE) 4: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x95918) [0x55fb067b9918]
(EE) 5: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0xbfbe9) [0x55fb067e3be9]
(EE) 6: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7f7a59290000+0x350e0) [0x7f7a592c50e0]
(EE) 7: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x7f7a5a39d000+0x198d8) [0x7f7a5a3b68d8]
(EE) 8: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x7f7a5a39d000+0x57d31) [0x7f7a5a3f4d31]
(EE) 9: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (pixman_image_composite32+0x451) [0x7f7a5a3a8711]
(EE) 10: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so (fbComposite+0x208) [0x7f7a4e4ec5b8]
(EE) 11: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so (0x7f7a54906000+0x1ac30) [0x7f7a54920c30]
(EE) 12: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so (0x7f7a54906000+0x1b4db) [0x7f7a549214db]
(EE) 13: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x13d3b1) [0x55fb068613b1]
(EE) 14: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x133064) [0x55fb06857064]
(EE) 15: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x573f7) [0x55fb0677b3f7]
(EE) 16: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x5b596) [0x55fb0677f596]
(EE) 17: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f7a592b1b45]
(EE) 18: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x4590e) [0x55fb0676990e]
(EE)
(EE) [mi] EQ overflow continuing.  600 events have been dropped.
(EE)
(EE) Backtrace:
(EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x56) [0x55fb068dad46]
(EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (QueuePointerEvents+0x52) [0x55fb06792e12]
(EE) 2: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f7a54f5d000+0x609a) [0x7f7a54f6309a]
(EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f7a54f5d000+0x655d) [0x7f7a54f6355d]
(EE) 4: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x95918) [0x55fb067b9918]
(EE) 5: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0xbfbe9) [0x55fb067e3be9]
(EE) 6: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7f7a59290000+0x350e0) [0x7f7a592c50e0]
(EE) 7: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x7f7a5a39d000+0x198d8) [0x7f7a5a3b68d8]
(EE) 8: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x7f7a5a39d000+0x57d31) [0x7f7a5a3f4d31]
(EE) 9: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (pixman_image_composite32+0x451) [0x7f7a5a3a8711]
(EE) 10: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so (fbComposite+0x208) [0x7f7a4e4ec5b8]
(EE) 11: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so (0x7f7a54906000+0x1ac30) [0x7f7a54920c30]
(EE) 12: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so (0x7f7a54906000+0x1b4db) [0x7f7a549214db]
(EE) 13: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x13d3b1) [0x55fb068613b1]
(EE) 14: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x133064) [0x55fb06857064]
(EE) 15: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x573f7) [0x55fb0677b3f7]
(EE) 16: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x5b596) [0x55fb0677f596]
(EE) 17: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f7a592b1b45]
(EE) 18: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x4590e) [0x55fb0676990e]
(EE)
(EE) [mi] EQ overflow continuing.  700 events have been dropped.
(EE)
(EE) Backtrace:
(EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x56) [0x55fb068dad46]
(EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (QueuePointerEvents+0x52) [0x55fb06792e12]
(EE) 2: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f7a54f5d000+0x609a) [0x7f7a54f6309a]
(EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f7a54f5d000+0x655d) [0x7f7a54f6355d]
(EE) 4: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x95918) [0x55fb067b9918]
(EE) 5: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0xbfbe9) [0x55fb067e3be9]
(EE) 6: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7f7a59290000+0x350e0) [0x7f7a592c50e0]
(EE) 7: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x7f7a5a39d000+0x198d8) [0x7f7a5a3b68d8]
(EE) 8: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x7f7a5a39d000+0x57d31) [0x7f7a5a3f4d31]
(EE) 9: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (pixman_image_composite32+0x451) [0x7f7a5a3a8711]
(EE) 10: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so (fbComposite+0x208) [0x7f7a4e4ec5b8]
(EE) 11: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so (0x7f7a54906000+0x1ac30) [0x7f7a54920c30]
(EE) 12: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so (0x7f7a54906000+0x1b4db) [0x7f7a549214db]
(EE) 13: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x13d3b1) [0x55fb068613b1]
(EE) 14: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x133064) [0x55fb06857064]
(EE) 15: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x573f7) [0x55fb0677b3f7]
(EE) 16: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x5b596) [0x55fb0677f596]
(EE) 17: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f7a592b1b45]
(EE) 18: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x4590e) [0x55fb0676990e]
(EE)
(EE) [mi] EQ overflow continuing.  800 events have been dropped.
(EE)
(EE) Backtrace:
(EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x56) [0x55fb068dad46]
(EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (QueuePointerEvents+0x52) [0x55fb06792e12]
(EE) 2: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f7a54f5d000+0x609a) [0x7f7a54f6309a]
(EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f7a54f5d000+0x655d) [0x7f7a54f6355d]
(EE) 4: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x95918) [0x55fb067b9918]
(EE) 5: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0xbfbe9) [0x55fb067e3be9]
(EE) 6: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7f7a59290000+0x350e0) [0x7f7a592c50e0]
(EE) 7: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x7f7a5a39d000+0x198d8) [0x7f7a5a3b68d8]
(EE) 8: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x7f7a5a39d000+0x57d31) [0x7f7a5a3f4d31]
(EE) 9: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (pixman_image_composite32+0x451) [0x7f7a5a3a8711]
(EE) 10: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so (fbComposite+0x208) [0x7f7a4e4ec5b8]
(EE) 11: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so (0x7f7a54906000+0x1ac30) [0x7f7a54920c30]
(EE) 12: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so (0x7f7a54906000+0x1b4db) [0x7f7a549214db]
(EE) 13: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x13d3b1) [0x55fb068613b1]
(EE) 14: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x133064) [0x55fb06857064]
(EE) 15: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x573f7) [0x55fb0677b3f7]
(EE) 16: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x5b596) [0x55fb0677f596]
(EE) 17: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f7a592b1b45]
(EE) 18: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x4590e) [0x55fb0676990e]
(EE)
(EE) [mi] EQ overflow continuing.  900 events have been dropped.
(EE)
(EE) Backtrace:
(EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x56) [0x55fb068dad46]
(EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (QueuePointerEvents+0x52) [0x55fb06792e12]
(EE) 2: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f7a54f5d000+0x609a) [0x7f7a54f6309a]
(EE) 2: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f7a54f5d000+0x609a) [0x7f7a54f6309a]
(EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f7a54f5d000+0x655d) [0x7f7a54f6355d]
(EE) 4: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x95918) [0x55fb067b9918]
(EE) 5: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0xbfbe9) [0x55fb067e3be9]
(EE) 6: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7f7a59290000+0x350e0) [0x7f7a592c50e0]
(EE) 7: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x7f7a5a39d000+0x198d8) [0x7f7a5a3b68d8]
(EE) 8: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x7f7a5a39d000+0x57d31) [0x7f7a5a3f4d31]
(EE) 9: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (pixman_image_composite32+0x451) [0x7f7a5a3a8711]
(EE) 10: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so (fbComposite+0x208) [0x7f7a4e4ec5b8]
(EE) 11: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so (0x7f7a54906000+0x1ac30) [0x7f7a54920c30]
(EE) 12: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so (0x7f7a54906000+0x1b4db) [0x7f7a549214db]
(EE) 13: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x13d3b1) [0x55fb068613b1]
(EE) 14: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x133064) [0x55fb06857064]
(EE) 15: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x573f7) [0x55fb0677b3f7]
(EE) 16: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x5b596) [0x55fb0677f596]
(EE) 17: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f7a592b1b45]
(EE) 18: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x4590e) [0x55fb0676990e]
(EE)
(EE) [mi] EQ overflow continuing.  1000 events have been dropped.
(EE) [mi] No further overflow reports will be reported until the clog is cleared.
(EE)
(EE) Backtrace:
(EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x56) [0x55fb068dad46]
(EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (QueuePointerEvents+0x52) [0x55fb06792e12]
(EE) 2: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f7a54f5d000+0x609a) [0x7f7a54f6309a]
(EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7f7a54f5d000+0x655d) [0x7f7a54f6355d]
(EE) 4: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x95918) [0x55fb067b9918]
(EE) 5: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0xbfbe9) [0x55fb067e3be9]
(EE) 6: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x7f7a59290000+0x350e0) [0x7f7a592c50e0]
(EE) 7: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x7f7a5a39d000+0x198d8) [0x7f7a5a3b68d8]
(EE) 8: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x7f7a5a39d000+0x57d31) [0x7f7a5a3f4d31]
(EE) 9: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (pixman_image_composite32+0x451) [0x7f7a5a3a8711]
(EE) 10: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so (fbComposite+0x208) [0x7f7a4e4ec5b8]
(EE) 11: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so (0x7f7a54906000+0x1ac30) [0x7f7a54920c30]
(EE) 12: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so (0x7f7a54906000+0x1b4db) [0x7f7a549214db]
(EE) 13: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x13d3b1) [0x55fb068613b1]
(EE) 14: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x133064) [0x55fb06857064]
(EE) 15: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x573f7) [0x55fb0677b3f7]
(EE) 16: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x5b596) [0x55fb0677f596]
(EE) 17: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f7a592b1b45]
(EE) 18: /usr/bin/X (0x55fb06724000+0x4590e) [0x55fb0676990e]
(EE)
```

Any idea what to do with this? Is there any bugtracker I should send this to?

Comment: This is probably a low-level graphics driver problem with your Radeon card. It does not process mouse cursor events anymore. The queue is full. It might be a bug or a broken card.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I filed a bug [here](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=97827).